# Run time error 9 while calculating in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I am populating an array OccGroupELT from a sheet and doing some calculation afterwards. I am getting runtime error 9 : subscript out of range when outer loop reaches to i = 9541 tries to assign value to OccGroupELT(9541,1). Any idea why this would be happening?

```
Dim OccGroupELT(9554, 9) AS Variant
OccGroupELT = Sheets("Main").Range("ED15:EL" & ELTRowNum).Value


For i = 1 To ELTRowNum
    For j = 3 To PerilCount + 2
        OccGroupELT(i, j) = OccGroupELT(i, j) * (1 + ALEA)
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range goes from row **15** to row `ELTRowNum` so you cannot loop from **1** to `ELTRowNum`. You should loop to `ELTRowNum - 14` instead, or better yet use `LBound` and `Ubound`:

```
For i = Lbound(OccGroupELT, 1) To UBound(OccGroupELT, 1)
```